# COmplex analysis Line integrals

Tags: integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Show that the $\mid\int(e^z-\bar{z})\mid$ over the positive oriented triangle  γ with end  points $z = 0$  $ z = 3i$ and  $z = −4$ is less than 60.$$\mid\int(e^z-\bar{z})\mid<60$$ WHy i cannot say that the line integral over a closed curve is zero so its modulus(absolute value)  is zero .

Comment: The integral  of g over a simple closed curve C is 0 if g is analytic on an open set that includes C and the region inside C. The function $\bar z$ is not analytic.But $e^z $ is. So $\int_T(e^z-\bar z=\int_T\bar z$ .($T$ is your triangle.)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Cauchyy-Goursat theorem tells us that the integral of an analytic function over any closed curve is zero. But $e^z-\overline z$ is not analytic. More specifically, $\overline z$ is not analytic. You'll have to do it the old fashioned way.

Comment: Any constant Function is analytic right?suppose f=1 then $\int(f)dz$ over a circle which is a closed curve should zero and not the length of the circle why im confused?

Comment: Don't let your intuition get the better of you! If $f(z)=1$, then $\int f(x)\,|dz|$ is indeed the perimeter of the circle, but usually we integrate $\int f(z)\,dz$, where we are integrating on a complex path. For every unit we travel in the real direction along the path, we will later travel backward that same amount. The same for the complex direction. So the integral will be zero.

Comment: ooh i get it . integrating to something diff than the complex path like length of the z the theorem does not apply.

Comment: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720377/complex-analysis-line-integrals?noredirect=1#comment3512184_1720377