# Complex analysis.Line integrals

Tags: calculus, integration, complex-analysis, multivariable-calculus

Show that the $\mid\int(e^z-\bar{z})\mid$ over the positive oriented triangle  γ with end  points $z = 0$  $ z = 3i$ and  $z = −4$ is less than 60.$$\mid\int(e^z-\bar{z})\mid<60$$ Now i know on my curve $Re(z)<0$ and $\mid{z}\mid$<4 or equal . So

$\mid\int(e^z-\bar{z})\mid \leq \int\mid(e^z-\bar{z})\mid) \leq \int\mid(e^z\mid+\mid\bar{z})\mid =\int e^{Re(z)}+\mid z \mid \leq \int e^0+4=5\int dz$ Now $\int dz$ is zero because gamma is a closed curve right? SO i prove the modulus is negative.Where am i wrong?

Comment: Related : http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1720321/

Comment: I asked that question too.

Comment: After your first inequality you have no more a *complex* integral

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your string of inequalities should go this way:
\begin{align*}
\left|\int_\gamma (e^z-\overline z)\,dz\right|&\leq\int_\gamma |e^z-\overline z|\,|dz|\\
&\leq\int_\gamma \left(|e^z|+|z|\right)\,|dz|\\
&\leq\int_\gamma (e^0+4)\,|dz|\\
&=5\int_\gamma |dz|.
\end{align*}
Notice that the $|dz|$ is now a real differential. While $\int_\gamma\,dz=0$, $\int_\gamma |dz|$ is equal to the arc length of $\gamma$.

Comment: Very nice explanation. +1

Comment: Would it be correct the break the integral to $\int(e^z) + \int\mid z \mid$ and say the first is zero and the other less/equal to $4 \int |dz|$

Comment: That is also fine.

Answer (score 0):

The perimeter of the triangle $\;T\;$ is

$$\ell(T):=3+5+4=12$$

so by Cauchy's Estimate:

$$\left|\oint_T(e^z+\overline z)dz\right|\le\int_{T}(|e^z|+|z|)dz<(e^0+4)\ell(T)=5\cdot12=60$$